# Is Expectation of Maximum of two Convex Random Variables Convex?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume that  $\xi_1(x)$  and $\xi_2(y)$ are two non-negative independent random variables 
with 
pdf 
$f(x,\tau)$,  $f(y,\tau)$ 
and 
cdf 
$F(x,\tau)$,  $F(y,\tau)$, 
where $x$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are parameters.

We know, that their expected values 
$$
E[\xi_1(x)] = \mu(x),
$$ 
$$
E[\xi_2(y)] = \mu(y),
$$

where $\mu$ is a convex function.

It is known, that the expected value  $ M(x, y) = E[max\{\xi_1(x), \xi_2(y)\}]$ is

$$
M(x,y) = \int_0^\infty F(x,\tau)f(y, \tau) \tau d\tau + 
\int_0^\infty F(y,\tau)f(x, \tau) \tau d \tau. 
$$

Is $M(x,y)$ convex?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It isn’t. For instance, for $n=1$, take $\xi_1(x)=0$ and $\xi_2(y)=\pm\sqrt{|y|}$ with probability $\frac12$ each. Then $\mu(x)=\mu(y)=0$ is convex, but $M(x,y)=\frac12\sqrt{|y|}$ isn’t.

Comment: What is $n$? But the pdf of $\xi_1$ is $f_1(x,\tau)=\delta(\tau)$, whereas the pdf of $\xi_2$ is $f_2(y,\tau)=\frac{1}{2}(\delta(\tau-\sqrt{|y|})+\delta(\tau+\sqrt{|y|}))$. I thought the 2 pdf had to be the same in the OP question (he uses always the same letter $f$) ? Or am I getting confused ?

Comment: @Thomas The notation in the original question is confusing/contradictory: ($\mu(x)$ and $\mu(y)$ does not make sense since it would seem $\mu(x)=\mu(y)$ whenever $x=y$, but I don't think that is what the asker wants).  This answer is a good interpretation of the notation, but it seems to validate the notation which I do not like.  I have plus-1d but I would like to plus-(1/2).

Comment: Better notation is that we have an uncountably infinite collection of random variables that are parameterized by $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, call them $W_x$ and $Z_x$.  We know $E[W_x]=m_W(x)$ and $E[Z_x]=m_Z(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $m_W(x)$ and $m_Z(x)$ are convex in $x$. It is not clear if we are supposed to assume $m_W(x)=m_Z(x)$ for all $x$, or not. Also, I'm not sure what "independent" is supposed to mean: Are $W_x$ and $Z_x$ independent for all $x$?  Are $W_x$ and $Z_y$ independent for all $(x;y)$?

Comment: Yes it is difficult to understand the problem. I think that the OP notation could suggest that $W_x$ and $Z_x$ have the additional constraint to be equally distributed for every value of the parameter $x$. That is suggested by the fact that only a $\mu$ function is defined. Anyway one can try to answer the different versions of the problem ...

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I noticed the problem with $\mu(x)=\mu(y)$ but didn't mention it because with all the expectations zero the example works regardless of how this notational issue is resolved. Funny, I sometimes feel a bit nitpicking when I point out all the errors in the question; now for once I didn't do it and it draws criticism :-)

Comment: I did not want to criticize I just wrote my understanding of the question. It is a good exercise even doing that :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight modification of the example already proposed. Let's have $\xi_1(x)=\pm \sqrt{|x|}$ and $\xi_2(y)=\pm \sqrt{|y|}$ each value with probability $1/2$.

If we call $f_1(x,*)$ and $f_2(y,*)$ the associated parametrized pdfs, than there is in this case a common parameterized pdf $f(z,*)$ such that, $f_1(x,*)=f(x,*)$ and $f_2(y,*)=f(y,*)$.

We now have $E[\xi_1(x)]=E[\xi_2(y)]=0$ and we can define $Z(x,y)=max(\xi_1(x),\xi_2(y))$.

From an explicit computation (there are just 4 combinations to consider because we consider the variables independent):

$E[Z(x,y)]=\sqrt{max(|x|,|y|)}/2$

which is not convex in $x,y$.